# Booting from cd, where do files go?

Tags: linux, dvd

I have brought ubuntu on a DVD and I'm booting the system from it using the option "try ubuntu without installing it".

When I download files and save them, where are they saved on the computer and can I restore them the next time I boot from the DVD?

Comment: You probably need to take a look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence). As far as, restoring the data after normally booting through a live disc and restarting the PC, that's not possible. All data is lost as soon as you exit that instance. Any changes you make during the session is volatile.

Answer (score 4):

The data is usually stored on a virtual drive made up of RAM. Hence, when you reboot, the data is lost. But you also can mount the hard drives within your computer after booting, and move the downloaded files onto those drives. Then, they're still available after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in a temporary directory like /proc/ or /tmp/. /proc/ is a ramdisk filesystem that runs most temporary process in Linux / Unix operating systems. If you do a cat /proc/ or I would at least do less /proc/ so you don't get a crap ton of $1 data.

Hope that helps